# postgres assgining same numbers to multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a database table with address information like below.

> address 1 　　　 |    address 2　　|　　city  　　　　|　state 　|　location id 
>   123 street name　|  bldg 1234　　|　Houston　　　|　TX　　|　12345
>   123 street name　|  bldg 1234　　|　Houston　　　|　TX　　|　67890
>   456 street name　|  bldg 7890　　|　New Orleans　|　LA　　|　56789
>   789 street name　|  bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　98765
>   789 street name　|  bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　53218
>   789 street name　|  bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　13579

So even though locations have same address, they all have different ID. 
What I am trying to do is add a new column called 'group_number' which will group all location id that have same address.

This is my expected outcome.

> Group Number | address 1 　　　 | address 2　　|　　city  　　　　|　state 　|　location id 
>   1　　　　　　 | 123 street name　|    bldg 1234　　|　Houston　　　|　TX　　|　12345
>   1　　　　　　 | 123 street name　|    bldg 1234　　|　Houston　　　|　TX　　|　67890
>   2　　　　　　 | 456 street name　|    bldg 7890　　|　New Orleans　|　LA　　|　56789
>   3　　　　　　 | 789 street name　|    bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　98765
>   3　　　　　　 | 789 street name　|    bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　53218
>   3　　　　　　 | 789 street name　|    bldg 0121　　|　long beach　　|　CA　　　|　13579

I tried use windows functions like rank(), row_num() and dense_rank()
and partition by address1||city||state

I thought that those functions may allow you to have same ranks in each partition.
But all those functions assign ranking/sequential row numbers by partition.

Can you help me figure out the best function to create group numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `dense_rank()` used like this:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by address1, address2, city, state) as GroupNumber,
       address1, address2, city, state, locationid
from addresses a;
```

You don't need the `partition by` at all for what you want to do.

Comment: This still doesn't work. Event with the same address and other information this gives me a different rank number.

Comment: @user2747356 . . . This should give the same id if all four fields are the same.  Perhaps there are subtle differences in the values in each row.